# SharePoint 2010: The menu of the site automatically hides for a user group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, permissions, navigation

I have a sub site (let's say SiteA) in my main SharePoint internal site. There is a user group (let's say GroupA) for the SiteA. All the users in GroupA have Viewer permission for the SharePoint site but and few users have Designer and Contributors right.

One fine morning, the GroupA users reported that they were not able to see some tabs of the navigation in SharePoint site. And another problem was some user seeing some tabs and other users were seeing another tab, all they were able to see random navigation menus.

I looked into the issue but got no success. And no other user group was facing this problem.

Next day, GroupA informed me that now they are able to see the navigations properly and its fixed automatically.

**My question is what could cause this issue?** I tried finding on the internet but no luck. I really want to know the root cause for the issue.